# MySql General error: 2053

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm getting the error:

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053

I have no idea why this is happening because the code works fine and the database is updated, but it still returns this error.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
require 'UHCauth.php';
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_serv;dbname=$mysql_db", $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

if(isset($_GET['d6518e47'])) {
    $USERNAME = $_GET['d6518e47'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "UPDATE $mysql_table
        SET KILLS = KILLS+1 WHERE USERNAME = :USERNAME"
    );
    $stmt->execute(array('USERNAME' => $USERNAME));

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($row);
} else {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM $mysql_table
        ORDER BY
            McVersion DESC,
            ModVersion DESC
        LIMIT 1"
    );
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($row);
}
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to fetch results from an `UPDATE` query?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-client.html#error_cr_no_result_set  It's because of `$stmt->fetch()` after the `UPDATE` query, which does not return rows.

Comment: Actually, it's because I edited some previous code that I had and forgot to remove the bit that returns something in JSON format. Also, that just solved my problem. I removed the JSON code and now I'm not getting the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` is the line that will cause your error.

Why?

Because there's nothing to fetch - in array - after an update

Remember that

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned
>   in your result set

So, no result set ... no party

If you want to know exit status of your command, just use the return value of `execute()` function

`$rv = $stmt->execute(array('USERNAME' => $USERNAME));`

Comment: Yep. I had copied this code from another project and forgot to remove that bit. Thanks!