# MYSQL queries to update the hierarchy of parent id of branch table related to ManagerID of user table

Tags: mysql

I have  users and branch tables with following data

```
     **users table**
    id    ManagerID
    1      3
    2      1
    3      5
    4      null
    5       4

    **Branch Table**
    id  parent_ID related_user_id 
    100               4
    200               3
    300               5   
    400               1
```

**parent_ID is reference with id(branch Table) in Branch table.
ManagerID is parent of id(users table) in user table.
id 4 has null ManagerID means no parent.

Now all ManagerID is already available in branch table which are basically the id of the user table now I need to update the parent id from the id of 
Branch table.
As from Above example the ManagerID of id 1 is 3 in user table and id 3 is available as related_user_id corresponding to id 200 in Manager table.
So the parent id for id 1 should be 200.
I need to update from above information in a single query and result should be

```
    **Branch Table**
    id  parent_ID related_user_id 
    100    null       4
    200    300        3
    300    100        5   
    400    200        1
```

please provide me solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
UPDATE Branch b1
  JOIN users u ON u.id = b1.related_user_id
  LEFT JOIN Branch b2 ON b2.related_user_id = u.ManagerID
   SET b1.parent_ID = b2.id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a070d/1/0)

Comment: Thankyou SO MUCH. That is the exact solution I want.,

Comment: But can you please help me  as Query runs ok, and everything is running well  but I am getting an error like:
General error: 2053 (SQL: UPDATE Branch b1
  JOIN users u ON u.id = b1.related_user_id
  LEFT JOIN Branch b2 ON b2.related_user_id = u.ManagerID
   SET b1.parent_ID = b2.id;) what should i do to resolve this

Comment: @ak001 Looks like a PHP error. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423717/mysql-general-error-2053) will help.